# Convert this plot to squarewave

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have the following pinescript code;

```
High10 = ta.highest(high, 10)
plot(High10, title='High10', linewidth=2, color=color.lime)
```

The plot looks something like this;

[image]

I want to convert this plot to look like a square wave by removing the slope. This can be done by flat lining the parts which are sloping.

I am using pinescript v5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your plot's style to `style=plot.style_stepline` for that.

It would look like below (white line is the original line):

[image]